# ZeroMQ Java Installation Problem

Tags: java, macos, zeromq

I'm trying to install ZeroMQ's [Java library](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq) but I've been having problem. First error was ./configure complained about JAVA_HOME which everything seemed to be fine but I couldn't manage to solve it but I've found a particular solution in [ZeroMQ's chat logs](http://travlr.github.com/zmqirclog/2010-August.html).

The suggested solution was;

```
JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home" ./configure
```

However it doesn't work for me. The error message I've been receiving is

```
checking for jni.h in /Library/Java/Home/include... configure: error: cannot find jni.h in /Library/Java/Home/include.
```

I've tried `JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home" ./configure` and `JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home" ./configure` as well but still no luck. I'd like to hear StackOverflowers' thoughts about how I can solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Since I installed JDK1.7 from oracle, so I need to specify another `JAVA_HOME`.

```
# prepare java home
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk/Contents/Home
cd $JAVA_HOME
sudo ln -s include Headers
# fix jni_md.h: No such file or directory problem during `make`
sudo cp include/darwin/* include/
cd -
# do real stuff
git clone http://github.com/zeromq/jzmq
cd jzmq
./autogen.sh
JAVAC=$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then do a test with: (note: the first `local_lat` will quit by itself after the test)

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -classpath /usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar:perf/ local_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 30 100 &
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -classpath /usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar:perf/ remote_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 30 100
```

Should got `mean latency` printed.

Comment: works for me! thanks! If you use JDK from oracle, then sym link Headers folder under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk/Contents/Home.

Answer (score 4):

What I did for the missing jni.h on Mac OSX Snow Leopard:

cd /Library/Java/Home

sudo ln -s /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Headers/ ./include

Comment: that was easy! thanks! and thank Apple for driving us crazy yet another time.